# C# TaskCanceledException and my CPU shoots to 100% (process is slowed down incredible)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have this code to download data from multiple websites.
I need to run this code for about 50.000 times.

However after running the code for 2 minutes (about 4000 times) I get the TaskCanceledException and my CPU goes to 100% and my process slows down incredibly.

This is the code:

```
        public async Task<string[]> GetDataAsync(string address, string postalCode)
    {
        var path = $"{address} {postalCode}/"; // build proper path for request
        var textFrom1 = "";
        string textFrom3 = "";
        string textFrom2 = "";
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                textFrom1 = await client.GetStringAsync("http://website1.com/" + path);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e) //404
            {

                await Task.Delay(10000); // try every 10 seconds (so I do not bomb the server with requests).
            }
        }


        if (textFrom1.Split(':', ',')[1] == "0")
        {
            return new string[] { "null", "null", "null", "null", "null" };
        }


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                textFrom2 = await client.GetStringAsync("http://website2.com/" + textFrom1.Split('"', '"')[11]);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000);
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                textFrom3 = await client.GetStringAsync("http://website3.com/" + textFrom2.Split('"', '"')[3]);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000);
            }
        }
        var allData = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(textFrom3));

        var item = allData.First();
        return new string[] { item.item1, item.item2, item.item3, item.item4, item.item5 };
    }
```

And this is the way I create my tasks:

```
        public string[][] GetAll(
        IEnumerable<string> adresses,
        IEnumerable<string> postalCodes)
    {
        // Start all tasks one by one without waiting for responses

        var tasks = adresses.Zip(postalCodes, (addr, code) => { return GetDataAsync(addr, code); });

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;

    }
```

Is there any way I can optimize my code, so that I do not have this exception and therefor not slowing down my process?

I hope someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: It is a firehose problem, too many tasks that take too long to complete.  The Debug > Windows > Threads window can show you it exploding.  You are likely to run out of memory.  Threadpool.SetMaxThreads() is a crude but simple countermeasure.

Comment: I'd dare say that introducing a `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the number of active `Task`s is an even simpler (if also crude) workaround. Still, a better solution would be not to create a gazillion `Task` instances in a single hit to begin with. TPL dataflow or a similar framework that lets you specify the maximum degree of parallelism would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are reaching the maximum number of tasks windows can handle at once. You could split your 50.000 requests to smaller groups or write some code to handle your running async-tasks to make sure that you don't start too much tasks at once.

Furthermore you probably reach the maximum number of ports. Everytime starting a new connection your application will open a new dynamic port.

Comment: Thanks, split the list into more tasks and that is working great! :)